# Delete Directory (UnauthorizedAccessException)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to delete a directory that was created by Service Fabric, but it just throws an exception.

```
PS C:\SfDevCluster\log> Remove-Item -path .\Traces\ -recurse -force
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\SfDevCluster\log\Traces\fabric_traces_9.1.1390.9590_133197288382564134_0.etl: Access to the path is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item -path .\Traces\ -recurse -force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (fabric_traces_9...382564134_0.etl:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\SfDevCluster\log\Traces\lease_traces_9.1.1390.9590_133197288382737081_0.etl: Access to the path is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item -path .\Traces\ -recurse -force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (lease_traces_9....382737081_0.etl:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\SfDevCluster\log\Traces\: Mappen er ikke tom.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item -path .\Traces\ -recurse -force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\SfDevCluster\log\Traces\:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

When I try get-acl on the two files that are in this directory, it won't even allow me to do that.

```
PS C:\SfDevCluster\log\Traces> get-acl *
get-acl : Ingen tilgang
At line:1 char:1
+ get-acl *
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Acl], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
```

When I run get-acl on the directory:

```
PS C:\SfDevCluster\log> Get-Acl .\Traces\ |  Format-List


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\SfDevCluster\log\Traces\
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administratorer
Group  : NT-MYNDIGHET\SYSTEM
Access : BUILTIN\Administratorer Allow  FullControl
         NT-MYNDIGHET\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Brukere Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
         NT-MYNDIGHET\Godkjente brukere Allow  Modify, Synchronize
         NT-MYNDIGHET\Godkjente brukere Allow  -536805376
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:BAG:SYD:(A;OICIID;FA;;;BA)(A;OICIID;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;AU)(A;OICIIOID;SDGXGWGR;;;AU)
```

The current user is also member of "administratorer", so I'm not sure I understand why I don't get access here;). Any pointers?

```
PS C:\SfDevCluster\log\Traces> whoami
puter\caec
PS C:\SfDevCluster\log\Traces> net user caec|select-string medlem

Medlemskap i lokal gruppe        *Administratorer
Medlemskap i global gruppe:      *Ingen
```

Running takeown, I get ownership of the directory, but the files inside still gives "Ingen Tilgang", which means "Access Denied". I'm not sure how I can force the command to give output in English.

```
takeown /F .\Traces\ /R /D Y

SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "C:\SfDevCluster\log\Traces\" now owned by user "puter\caec".

INFO: Ingen tilgang. ( "C:\SfDevCluster\log\Traces\fabric_traces_9.1.1390.9590_133197288382564134_0.etl" )

INFO: Ingen tilgang. ( "C:\SfDevCluster\log\Traces\lease_traces_9.1.1390.9590_133197288382737081_0.etl" )
```

I get this when looking at permission properties in the GUI.

```
You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings.
```

I'm pretty sure this resolves by the classic Windows reboot, but I've seen this problem many times and I need to understand why.

Comment: The files may have set individual owners and individual permissions; those take precedence over anything set on the directory. Taking ownership and checking is easy to do from Explorer; a little less so in PowerShell due to the clunky ACL API. `takeown` is quite a bit easier.

Comment: I've now tried to take ownership of the directory with files using takeown and added the sad output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually caused by the file you are trying to manipulate being locked by a process.

In this case. Windows will deny access to the file to any process other than that process.
You can open the Resource Monitor to see how this file is occupied, and you can unlock the file by terminating the process in question

Hope this works for you

(I don't speak English, so I've used translation software, so please forgive any inaccuracies)

Comment: No, the file is not locked. I've checked that in ResMon.

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @flower_elf